# Graficas interactivas python

Tags: python, json, plotly

Adjunto el código

```
    import plotly.express as px

# Crear el gráfico interactivo con plotly
fig = px.choropleth(merged, geojson=merged.geometry, locations=merged.index, color='2020M',
                    color_continuous_scale='Viridis', labels={'2020M':'2020M'},
                    hover_data={'provincia': merged['NAME_2']})



# Configurar el diseño del gráfico
fig.update_geos(fitbounds='locations', visible=False)

# Mostrar el gráfico interactivo
fig.show()
```

[image: Lo que obtengo del codigo] o modificar los valores que me da para todos.

Me gustaria saber como puedo graficar igual  que este grafico pero con las columnas que van del 2013M al 2020M y que los resultados se impriman en una misma salida en un 4x2 por ejemplo, ademas si puedo incluirle una leyenda manual yo a todos los graficos con los mismos valores para que sean uniformes, adjunto una imagen para que se vea el formato que quiero con leyenda e interactivo, ya que esta 2 foto no se puede hacer interactiva
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]